# Single-page website: How can I highlight links when user scrolls/clicks on item in nav bar?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

Yep, what I am trying to do is in the title. I basically have links that point to location on the same page. It is easing nicely now, but I can't get it to show current position by calling an ID or class to highlight the current nav item. I am using Jquery localScroll and scrollTo. I know that I have to "bind to scroll event", but I don't know what I am doing wrong. It just isn't working.

I've tried some possible solutions that seem to work for others, but when I add the script to my code, scrollTo and localScroll stops working (it doesn't ease anymore).

This is all I have so far in terms of JS (and of course the scrollTo and localScroll js files):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fixed_nav').localScroll({duration:700});
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you are using full page sections, then you could use [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for it? You can use it with the option `autoScrolling:false` to keep the appearance of a normal site, but you can link it with the menu so it get highlighted as [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html).

Comment: @Alvaro Thank you. My sections are not full page. I basically just followed this tutorial to achieve the easing: http://designshack.net/articles/html/how-to-link-to-specific-points-in-a-page-and-animate-the-scroll/ . But I want to add to it by making the nav bar highlight the current position when the user scrolls or clicks on a navigation item.